# How to XML request in PHP Curl or PHP Soapclient?

Tags: php, curl, soap, soap-client, php-curl

I am working on an XML request in PHP. Can we make the request with PHP CURL or PHP SoapClient? The following is a sample SOAP 1.2 :

```
POST /max/member.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: api.relateddigital.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <SendOngoingEMail xmlns="http://ws.euromsg.com/member">
      <ServiceTicket>string</ServiceTicket>
      <Key>string</Key>
      <Value>string</Value>
      <DemograficData>
        <EmKeyValue>
          <Key>string</Key>
          <Value>string</Value>
        </EmKeyValue>
        <EmKeyValue>
          <Key>string</Key>
          <Value>string</Value>
        </EmKeyValue>
      </DemograficData>
      <ForceUpdate>boolean</ForceUpdate>
      <OngoingCampaignId>string</OngoingCampaignId>
    </SendOngoingEMail>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the WSDL, you can use the native PHP [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) class. You'll have to pass either a PHP array or an object well structured.

I strongly advise you to use a WSDL to PHP generator. This way you'll use a suited PHP SDK based on the WSDL in order to use a fully OOP approach. Moreover, you won't wonder how to construct the request. Finally, the response handling will be eased thanks to the generated classes.

Try the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project.